# How to disable the button_to on rails when I click on button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button-to

I have a button on my Ruby on Rails app which calls a function on my controller.

When I click on the button I call a function.

So I want do disable this button after clicking on it, then able it again after my function was done.

How can I do it?

below my view code

```
<div style="float: left; width: auto; padding-right: 1%">
    <%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'repositories') %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable any button with `:disable_with` attribute. Try this :

```
<div style="float: left; width: auto; padding-right: 1%">
    <%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'repositories'), :disable_with => "Submitting...." %>
</div>
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. use `jquery-rails` gem
2. include `jquery`, `jquery_ujs` in your page
3. for `button_to_function` method use `'data-disable-with' => 'Submitting'`